# Creating lists in various ways

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

I can create the single-element list `(2)` in all of the following ways:

```
'(2)      
(list 2)  
(cons 2 nil)
```

However, why does the following give an error?

```
(2 . nil)
```

Is there no such thing as the "scalar null" value in scheme? Or is there an alternate way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(2 . '())` does indeed represent the singleton list `'(2)`: the latter is shorthand for the former. The problem is that, if you use it in the same context that you would use `(cons 2 '())` in, you get an error. Why? The same error you would get if you tried to evaluate `(2)`! That means to call `2` as a function, passing it no arguments.

If instead you want to just create such a list, without calling it, you do the same thing you would with the shorthand: quote it.

```
'(2 . ())
```